# Static Realm.framework is 300MB?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, realm

Today,i find that static ream.framework is very very large, It's more than 300MB. Now It's is too large to submit code. But I don't know why. Please help me ! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

From Realm's documentation ([source](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#how-big-is-the-realm-library)):

> Once your app is built for release, Realm should only add around 1MB to its size. The releases we distribute are significantly larger because they include support for iOS, watchOS and tvOS simulators, some debug symbols, and bitcode, which are all stripped by Xcode automatically when you build your app.

Comment: So is the case!  OK,Thanks.